# issue due to getAdapterPosition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an array which contains values like {seat 1,seat 1,seat 1,seat 2, seat 2, seat 3, seat 4,seat 4,seat 4}. ie Left side of image
I need to group them according to its seat values ie. Right side of image.
[image]

For given environment seat list array will be: `{"1", "-1", "-1", "2", "-1", "3", "4", "-1", "-1"}`
currently i am using recyclerview and checking this with below condition:

```
if(seat_list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).equals("-1"))
    {
        Log.d("aaa", "if :" + seat_list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()) );
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("aaa", "else :" + seat_list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()) );
        holder.ll_header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tv_seat_num.setText(seat_list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
    }
```

With above code list is getting destroyed on scrolling the recyclerview.
i already sorted but i want to give common header or heading to all orders with same seat

Comment: you can take a look at [this library](https://github.com/Karumi/HeaderRecyclerView)

Comment: @Kaushik i dont want to add header to recycler view... there will be header for particular items.see right side of image.

Comment: Is the list big? How big?

Comment: It can be from 5 to 150 @Tin Tran

Comment: Just do a for loop to create another list then use it in your adapter.

Comment: yes @TinTran.. Logically it is ok but issue is that when i scroll the data position  is not maintained. Main reason to use recyclerview was that only, to maintain position. But unfortunately it is not maintained in recycler view.

Comment: You can use **SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter**
 [https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter]

Comment: With above code list is getting destroyed on scrolling the recyclerview// what is the log  showing while the list gets destroyed? plz show it

Comment: @HariKrishnan Nothing special in the log. I printed position and adapterposition but i think I will have to change core logic of setting condition statements.

Comment: this is pretty simple problem but your question is not so clear it can be done using recyclerview only post your actual array list may be then I can hlp you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think your data ready to be displayed. So it`d be better to prepare it.
And it is better to have some typed data model, that contains info about seats and orders. OOP, you know ?
To keep example simple, I prepare and map data within activity, but it's not very good idea for real world projects. 
So, from your description, we have some array, where items could be duplicated and their position in array - it is orderId. So, in other way we want to have some grouped structure with key-value pair, where key -> № of Seat, and value -> collection of orderIds. But it will be much better to have a class, that represent such relations and have info about things described above.

With data like that, it will be not very big problem to just display them in recyclerView.

At the begining, I wanted to place just couple methods here, but after I realized that it may be confused without full code list. 
So, here you go all stuff.
This is result of what you will get with listed below code:

[image]

= = = = = time to see some code = = = = =

Activity -> (with only RecyclerView in xml layout)

```
public class SeatsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recycler;
SeatsAdapter seatsAdapter;
final String[] orders =
  { "seat 1", "seat 1", "seat 1", "seat 2", "seat 2", "seat 3", "seat 4", "seat 4", "seat 4" };

@Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_seats);
  setTitle("Seats example");
  recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
  recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

  final Map<String, List<Integer>> groupedOrders = groupData(orders);
  final List<SeatItem> seats = mapToSeatsItems(groupedOrders);

  bindToRecycler(seats);
}

private void bindToRecycler(List<SeatItem> seatItems) {
  seatsAdapter = new SeatsAdapter(seatItems);
  recycler.setAdapter(seatsAdapter);
}

private Map<String, List<Integer>> groupData(final String[] items) {
final Map<String, List<Integer>> grouped = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < items.length ; i++) {
  // I took it from your description. I image that orderId is the place of the seat in array
  final Integer orderId = i+1;
  final String headerKey = items[i];

  if (!grouped.containsKey(headerKey)){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(orderId);
    grouped.put(headerKey, list);
  } else {
    List<Integer> list = grouped.get(headerKey);
    list.add(orderId);
  }
}

  return grouped;
}

private List<SeatItem> mapToSeatsItems(Map<String, List<Integer>> groupOrders) {
  final List<SeatItem> list = new ArrayList<>(groupOrders.size());
  for (String key : groupOrders.keySet()) {
    final SeatItem item = new SeatItem(key, groupOrders.get(key));
    list.add(item);
  }
  return list;
  }
}
```

Then SeatItem, that represent data model (POJO, Bean, whatever)

```
public class SeatItem {
  public SeatItem(String header, List<Integer> orderIds) {
    this.header = header;
    this.orderIds = orderIds;
  }

  final String header;
  final List<Integer> orderIds;

  public String getHeader() {
    return header;
  }

  public List<Integer> getOrderIds() {
    return orderIds;
  }
}
```

SeatsAdapter ->

```
public class SeatsAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
final List<SeatItem> dataList;

  public SeatsAdapter(final List<SeatItem> items){
  dataList = items;
}

@Override public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup 
parent, int viewType) {
  final View view = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_seat, parent, 
false);
  return new SeatsViewHolder(view);
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int 
position) {
  final SeatsViewHolder seatsViewHolder = (SeatsViewHolder) holder;
  final SeatItem item = dataList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

  final StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < item.getOrderIds().size(); i++) {
    // here is not production ready, but for just example will be ok
    contentBuilder
        .append("order Id: ")
        .append(item.getOrderIds().get(i));
    if (i + 1 != item.getOrderIds().size()){
      contentBuilder.append("\n");
    }
  }
  seatsViewHolder.tvHeader.setText(item.getHeader());
  seatsViewHolder.tvContent.setText(contentBuilder);
}

@Override public int getItemCount() { return dataList.size(); }

private static class SeatsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  final TextView tvHeader;
  final TextView tvContent;

  SeatsViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    tvHeader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
    tvContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
  }
}
}
```

And the last one - item xml, that will be displayed by recycler

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="header! "
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#cccccc"

    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="content ! ! ! "
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:padding="8dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @VladymyrRtmnko: bounty just for efforts :)... I will accept as correct once I implement this code currectly :)

Answer (score -2):

You can sort using Collections.sort method

Comment: i already sorted but i want to give common header or heading to all orders with same seat